# embed google chart image in pdf with php

Tags: php

how do i embed an image generated by google charts into a PDF through php ??

Comment: Into an existing pdf? That is no easy task. The pdf file structure is very complex and good and complete parsers are non existent.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the pdf libs used. some will take a url as a param, others a direct path. for the url type just use the url directly to the chart. for the local path check out something like this:

https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/beta/core/google/views/helpers/google_app_helper.php#L26

and then just feed it the new path to the image.

Comment: i am actually creating an html file which has images inside it. i am downloading that html as a pdf using dompdf .. but its showing a red cross mark instead of the pic.

Comment: what about other images? there is not much info here.

Comment: If you're using dompdf 0.5.1 then it won't work. That version had problems with querystrings. The 0.6.0 release (currently at beta 2) can handle it.

Comment: i have embeded images using dompdf, but the problem now is that a few of the images are being rendered but some of them arent. any idea?

Comment: The source of an image rendering problem can be difficult to identify without some additional information: version of dompdf; version of PHP, PHP settings (notably allow_url_fopen; GD enabled), how the document is loaded, and how the images are referenced. Can you provide a sample document?